# SQL Server (terminal result) hierarchy map

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, gaps-and-islands

In **SQL Server 2016**, I have a table with the following chaining structure:

**dbo.Item**

| OriginalItem | ItemID |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | 7 |
| 1 | 2 |
| NULL | 1 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 |
| **NULL** | **8** |
| NULL | 5 |
| **9** | **11** |
| 2 | 3 |

> EDIT NOTE: **Bold** numbers were added as a response to @lemon comments below

> Importantly, this example is a trivialized version of the real data, and the neatly ascending entries is not something that is present in the actual data, I'm just doing that to simplify the understanding.

I've constructed a query to get what I'm calling the **TerminalItemID**, which in this example case is ItemID `4`, `6`, and `7`, and populated that into a temporary table **@TerminalItems**, the resultset of which would look like:

**@TerminalItems**

| TerminalItemID |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| **8** |
| **11** |

What I need, is a final *mapping* table that would look something like this (using the above example -- note that it also contains for `4`, `6`, and `7` mapping to themselves, this is needed by the business logic):

**@Mapping**

| ItemID | TerminalItemID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 |
| **8** | **8** |
| **9** | **11** |
| **11** | **11** |

What I need help with is how to build this last **@Mapping** table.  Any assistance in this direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the temporary table can be avoided utterly. Can you share the logic behind the construction of "*TerminalItems*"?

Comment: It's basically `SELECT (a.)ItemID AS TerminalItemID FROM Item a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Item b WHERE a.ItemID = b.OriginalItemID` -- where the `(a.)` is editorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical gaps-and-islands problem and can also be carried out without recursion in three steps:

- assign 1 at the beginning of each partition
- compute a running sum over your flag value (generated at step 1)
- extract the max "*ItemID*" on your partition (generated at step 2)

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN OriginalItem IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS changepartition 
    FROM Item
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(changepartition) OVER(ORDER BY ItemID) AS parts
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT ItemID, MAX(ItemID) OVER(PARTITION BY parts) AS TerminalItemID 
FROM cte2
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/CekoOtel).

Assumption: Your terminal id items correspond to the "*ItemID*" value preceding a NULL "*OriginalItem*" value.

---

**EDIT**: "*Fixing orphaned records.*"

The query works correctly when records are not orphaned. The only way to deal them, is to get missing records back, so that the query can work correctly on the full data.

This is carried out by an extra subquery (done at the beginning), that will apply a `UNION ALL` between:

- the available records of the original table
- the missing records

```
WITH fix_orphaned_records AS(
    SELECT * FROM Item

    UNION ALL

    SELECT NULL AS OriginalItem, 
           i1.OriginalItem AS ItemID
    FROM      Item i1
    LEFT JOIN Item i2 ON i1.OriginalItem = i2.ItemID
    WHERE i1.OriginalItem IS NOT NULL AND i2.ItemID IS NULL
), cte AS (
 ...
```

Missing records correspond to "*OriginalItem*" values that are never found within the "*ItemID*" field. A self left join will uncover these missing records.

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mbA4IwWo).

Comment: I may have trivialized the example too much, as this works for a lot of cases, but definitely produces over bucketing.  I don't know if a tweak is required to make this work correctly, because it seems like it could work with a tweak or two.  ItemID and OriginalItemID may be completely out of chronological order in the actual data set -- i.e. a record may need to tie literally thousands of rows back, not just immediately previous/next.  Any thoughts on how to modify?  This query is unequivocally the fastest, so would like to use if I can align it correctly.

Comment: Update your input tables and expected output of your post to reflect this behaviour. It will need most likely some tweaks, although I want to be sure about to understand your requirements well through an example.

Comment: updated input table to better reflect the reality of the data -- output table should remain the same

Comment: My query works with your updated data with no need of further changes. The `ORDER BY` clauses inside the window functions ensure the correctness of the output, regardless of the initial order of the rows. @Matt

Comment: So after doing some digging, it appears there are orphaned records in the actual data set, which is why this isn't working when I replicate it.  If you rerun your code with my updated source table, you'll see the disparity.  What I was seeing is the same thing you'll see: **both** `8` and `11` get mapped to `11`.

Comment: Getting back the missing rows to solve orphanage, automatically solves the problem. Check the latest update on this answer + fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help with this @lemon!!  Masterfully done!

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
with MyTbl as (
    select *
    from (values 
     (NULL, 1 )
    ,(1,    2 )
    ,(2,    3 )
    ,(3,    4 )
    ,(NULL, 5 )
    ,(5,    6 )
    ,(NULL, 7 )
    ) T(OriginalItem,   ItemID)
)
, TerminalItems as (
    /* Find all leaf level items: those not appearing under OriginalItem column */
    select LeafItem=ItemId, ImmediateOriginalItem=M.OriginalItem
    from MyTbl M
    where M.ItemId not in
                    (select distinct OriginalItem
                      from MyTbl AllParn
                      where OriginalItem is not null
                      )
), AllLevels as (
    /* Use a recursive CTE to find and report all parents */
    select ThisItem=LeafItem, ParentItem=ImmediateOriginalItem
    from TerminalItems
    union all
    select ThisItem=AL.ThisItem, M.OriginalItem
    from AllLevels AL
         inner join
         MyTbl M
         on M.ItemId=AL.ParentItem
     )
select ItemId=coalesce(ParentItem,ThisItem), TerminalItemId=ThisItem
from AllLevels
order by 1,2
```

Beware of the MAXRECURSION setting; by default SQLServer iterates through recursion 100 times; this would mean that the depth of your tree can be 100, max (the maximum number of nodes between a terminal item and its ultimate original item). This can be increased by `OPTION(MAXRECURSION nnn)` where nnn can be adjusted as needed. It can also be removed entirely by using `0` but this is not recommended because your data can cause infinite loops.

Comment: "Beware of the MAXRECURSION" -- That's a very important issue to consider.

Comment: Your query works well. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LSq8w7T7).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to compute the last item in the sequence. For example:

```
with
n (orig_id, curr_id, lvl) as (
  select itemid, itemid, 1 from item
 union all
  select n.orig_id, i.itemid, n.lvl + 1
  from n
  join item i on i.originalitem = n.curr_id
)
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by orig_id order by lvl desc) as rn from n
) x
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
 orig_id  curr_id  lvl  rn 
 -------- -------- ---- -- 
 1        4        4    1  
 2        4        3    1  
 3        4        2    1  
 4        4        1    1  
 5        6        2    1  
 6        6        1    1  
 7        7        1    1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6ox0_OUt).